# PHP Simple Search Form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm new to PHP and would like to start a simple query system by just searching identification number and it will print out full name, date of birth, gender and identification number.

The first file name of the page is *search.php*.
Inside of the file contains

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="result.php" method="get">
  ID Number: <input type="text" name="idnumber"> <input type="submit" value="Search"><br>
</form>

<p>Input ID number</p>

</body>
</html>
```

After that, I created a database named users and with following columns (`id, full_name, date_of_birth, gender, identification_number`)

What code should I write into result.php to let the search result of identification number match and found it will print all the details of the person and the search keyword must 100% match.

Example of the scenario.
In database has `John Doe, 20 September 1990, Male, 900920A44`.
Search keyword `"900920A44"` will print out corresponding user's information but if search keyword `"900920A"` will not print out anything because other user might had a `"900920A55"` identification number.

Files:

search.php & result.php

Please advise.

Comment: Where is your result.php file. Show your result.php code.

Comment: Well you have to type query for that. First take the string and send to page where you are having queries. Use that string in text and run select query with that and show the result in result.php. Simple

Comment: @NikhilVaghla I don't know how to start with the result.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

**FORM**

```
<html>
    <body>

    <form action="result.php" method="get">
      ID Number: <input type="text" name="idnumber"> <input type="submit" name="form_submit" value="Search"><br>

   //PUT THE NAME FOR SUBMIT BUTTON 

    </form>

    <p>Input ID number</p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**result.php**

```
    //database connection

     global $conn;

        $servername = "localhost";  //host name

        $username = "username"; //username

        $password = "password"; //password

        $mysql_database = "dbname"; //database name

        //mysqli prepared statement 

        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

       mysqli_select_db($conn,$mysql_database) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");



    if(isset($_GET['form_submit']))
    {

      $IDNUMBER =$_GET['idnumber'];



     $stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from your_table_name_here where identification_number=? ");

                    $stmt->bind_param('s',$IDNUMBER);

                    $stmt->execute();
                $val =  $stmt->get_result();
                $row_count= $val->num_rows;

                if($row_count>0)
                {
                    $result =$val->fetch_assoc();

                    print_r($result);
                }
                else
                {

                  echo "identification_number not Match";
                }



                    $stmt->close();
                     $conn->close();

    }
```

Comment: why id when op is talking about string search too??

Comment: Dear jothi,
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\result.php on line 31|

                    $stmt->bind_param('i',$IDNUMBER);

Comment: your table name or column name is not correct     your_table_name_here change by your table name

Comment: change line like this $stmt->bind_param('s',$IDNUMBER);   put s insted of i

Comment: if its work mean make it green tick .for future user reference @JunoFernando

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
login.php

<html>
<body>
<p>Input ID number</p>
<form action="result.php" method="get">
  ID Number: <input type="text" name="idnumber"> <input type="submit" value="Search"><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>

result.php

<?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "users";
mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database) or die("Could not select database");
 $idmark = $_GET['idnumber'];
$sql = "select * from student where identification_number = '".$idmark."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);?>
<table width="70%" border="1px solid black">
            <tr style="background-color:green; color:white">
                <th><strong>ID</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
                <th><strong>DOB</strong></th>
                <th><strong>GENDER</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Identification No</strong></th>

            </tr>
            <?php if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {  $i=0; 
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
      <tr class="<?php echo ($i%2) ? 'even' : 'odd' ?>">
                <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['full_name'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['date_of_birth'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['gender'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['identification_number'];?></td>

            </tr>


             <?php $i++;}}
?>
```

Comment: why id when op is talking about string search too??

Comment: @ Leo the lion Thanks  yeah its right now code has been changed.

Comment: The original MySQL extension is now deprecated, and will generate E_DEPRECATED errors when connecting to a database. Instead, use the MYSQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions.

Comment: @jothi thanks for info but it just and old code which i used here